# Concatinate 2 fields in CHtml::listData when output in yii dropdownlist

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'size', CHtml::listData(Size::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'width'. 'x' .'height' )); ?>
```

I'm creating a drop down menu and I want to concatenate the field width and height so that it would look like 10 x 10 in my drop down list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use an anonymous function to do that. I'll leave out your dropdown for clarity:

```
$dropDownData = CHtml::listData(Size::model()->findAll(), 'id', function($size) {
    return CHtml::encode($size->width . 'x'. $size->height);
});
```

Of course you need an appropriate PHP version for anonymous functions (5.3 and up, afair).

Comment: you are the master programmer. +1000 reputation :D

Answer (score 1):

For PHP version < 5.3 you can use the [virtual attribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/#hh0) concept... by adding the following method to the **Size** model:

```
public function getWxh()
{
    return $this->width . 'x' . $this->height;
}
```

and then use the **wxh** attribute directly:

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'size', CHtml::listData(Size::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'wxh' ));
```